# Need to frame a JSON format using Hive data

Tags: arrays, json, apache-spark, struct, hive

Could you please help me with the below requirement. I have a hive table data and using that need to frame the below JSON.

```
------------------------
Table : global_product
-------------------------
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Columns             Datatypes
------------------------------------------------------------------------
AAA                 varchar(10)
BBB                 varchar(10)
GEOGRAPHIC          array<struct<CCC:double,DDD:double>>    

select 
AAA, 
BBB, 
GEOGRAPHIC 
from global_product;
```

o/p:

```
 ind, 
 hyd, 
 [{"CCC":4.7,"DDD":7.6},{"CCC":5.1,"DDD":7.5}, {"CCC":5.7,"DDD":9.5}]
```

---

### Need to frame the JSON format using the above column data

```
"GLOBAL":
{
"PRODUCTS":
        "{
        "ITEMS":{"AAA":"ind","BBB":"hyd"},
        "GEOGRAPHIC":[
                        {"CCC":45.78,"DDD":87.56},
                        {"CCC":45.73,"DDD":97.59},
                        {"CCC":45.73,"DDD":97.59}
                    ]
                }"
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are okay with complex type

```
struct<global: struct<products: struct<items: struct<AAA:double, BBB:double>,
                                      geographic: array< struct<ccc: double, ddd: double> >
                                      >
                   > 
      >
```

Then you can use named_struct() construct. In this case all attribute names will be lowercased.

Demo

```
with your_data as (--This is initial data example
select 'ind' as AAA, 'hyd' as BBB, 
array(named_struct("CCC",4.7,"DDD",7.6),named_struct("CCC",5.1,"DDD",7.5), named_struct("CCC",5.7,"DDD",9.5)) as GEOGRAPHIC
)

select named_struct('GLOBAL', named_struct('PRODUCTS',named_struct('ITEMS', named_struct('AAA', AAA, 'BBB', BBB), 
                                            'GEOGRAPHIC', GEOGRAPHIC) 
                                          )  
                   )
     from your_data;
```

Result (not pretty-printed):

```
{"global":{"products":{"items":{"aaa":"ind","bbb":"hyd"},"geographic":[{"ccc":4.7,"ddd":7.6},{"ccc":5.1,"ddd":7.5},{"ccc":5.7,"ddd":9.5}]}}}
```

And if you are not happy with such complex type and want to have STRING like yours with attributes NOT lowercased, then explode array and concatenate everything

```
set hive.execution.engine=mr;
with your_data as (--This is initial data example, use your table instead of this example
select 'ind' as AAA, 'hyd' as BBB, 
array(named_struct("CCC",4.7,"DDD",7.6),named_struct("CCC",5.1,"DDD",7.5), named_struct("CCC",5.7,"DDD",9.5)) as GEOGRAPHIC
)

select    concat('"GLOBAL":\n{\n"PRODUCTS":\n          "{\n    "ITEMS":{"AAA":"',AAA,'","BBB":"',BBB,'"},', '\n',
          concat('     "GEOGRAPHIC": [\n         ',concat_ws(',',collect_list(concat('{"CCC": "',e.CCC, '", "DDD": "',DDD,'"}'))),
                 '\n          ]\n     }"\n }') 
          )
     from your_data --replace with your table name
          lateral view outer inline(GEOGRAPHIC) e as CCC, DDD
          group by AAA, BBB;
```

Result:

```
"GLOBAL":
{
"PRODUCTS":
          "{
    "ITEMS":{"AAA":"ind","BBB":"hyd"},
     "GEOGRAPHIC": [
         {"CCC": "4.7", "DDD": "7.6"},{"CCC": "5.1", "DDD": "7.5"},{"CCC": "5.7", "DDD": "9.5"}
          ]
     }"
 }
```

Just use your table instead of CTE in FROM and it will work with your data. I added newlines `\n` and spaces to produce similar formatting.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the immediate response. The 2nd output seems fine for me. And I have a small clarification on that.  Group by AAA, BBB is done there. But for me the group by should be done by AAA and select columns need to have AAA, BBB. In this case, how  it should be done, If you provide any suggestions, it will be helpful.

Comment: @Sr4 Why I have added AAA and BBB into groupby? Because there is aggregation (`collect_list`), and all columns not aggregated, used in the query (they are AAA and BBB) should be in groupby. But if you need to aggregate on diggerent group(AAA only) and have these columns AAA and BBB then the solution is to use analytic funtion instead of simple groupby aggregation:  `collect_list(blabla) over(partition by AAA) ` - this will result in dataset with the same list for same AAA, rows not grouped.

Comment: @Sr4 After that you may want to perform additional aggregation like min/max / or simple groupby or row_number to filter in upper subquery, etc in upper subquery to reduce rows if necessary, whatever you want to aggregate and only after that build your string using concat.

Comment: @Sr4 Welcome on SO! Please avoid asking additional questions in comments. We are not the free coding service.  I provided you with idea and spent enough time on your initial question. If it was useful, consider accepting please. If you have any other questions please create one more question, describe the problem  and show your efforts. Someone from community may help it found your question interesting